# how to request XML content type from rest-assured

Tags: xml, rest, junit, rest-assured

I have a REST api that supports json and xml. I would like to test the XML side but since upgreading to version 2.4.0 I am getting an error:

Expected content-type "XML" doesn't match actual content-type "application/json".

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

here are some test code samples that fail the tests.

```
    RequestSpecification requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setContentType("application/xml")
            .build();

    expect()
            .contentType(ContentType.XML)
            .statusCode(200)
            .given()
            .spec(requestSpec)
            .get("/resources/main/dictionaries");
```

I also tried to set the content type directly on the given()

```
    given()
            .contentType("application/xml")
            .expect()
            .contentType(ContentType.XML)
            .statusCode(404)
            .get("/resources/main/revisions/10000");
```

how do I force the request to get XML media type?

request log looks like this:

```
Request method: GET
Multiparts:             <none>
Headers:                Accept=*/*
                            Content-Type=application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
Body:                   <none>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `Accept` header:

```
given()
       .spec(requestSpec)
       .header("Accept", "application/xml")
       .get("/resources/main/revisions/10000")
```

Comment: thanks @monty0. That worked... I wonder why it worked before ver 2.4.x?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I have no idea why it would have worked in previous versions.